# Concatenate arrays of coordinates in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I am building an array of coordinates from multiple d-dimensional cubes. I would like to start with an empty array and append the coordinates that I generate in each for-loop. However, np.concatenate (and vstack) requires an existing array of matching dimensions. I also want to keep the dimension rather than getting a flat array.

This is the idea I would like to do:

```
#sample from d-dimensional cube
def make_cubes(d, npoints, ncubes):
    cubes = []
    for i in range(ncubes):
        c = np.random.rand(npoints, d)     #sample from cube in d dimensions
        c += np.random.uniform(-5,5)   #random translation
        cubes = np.concatenate((cubes, c))
    return cubes
```

To make it actually work, I have to define cubes as

```
cubes = [[]]
for d in range(d):
    cubes[0].append(np.nan)
```

Comment: So, what is the final shape of `cubes` meant to be? `(ncubes, npoints, d)`?

Comment: They could be anything, but for example I would want five 3dimensional cubes of 100 points each (d=3, ncubes=5, npoints=100). So cubes.shape = (500,3)

Comment: Repeated `np.concatenate` in a loop is a bad idea.  Use list `append` instead.

Comment: @900edges That entire line makes no sense at all. An array with shape `(500, 3)` is a 2D-array, not 3D. You would also know what the shape is based on the inputs, as you stated that it would be `(npoints*ncubes, d)`.
However, I think you are mistaken about what `np.random.rand` does. It returns an array with random values of the shape you gave it. So, if you would require an array with shape `(500, 3)`, then you can just ask for that immediately.

Comment: ```append``` removes the structure, giving a flattened-out array. How would you use it in this case? @hpaulj

Comment: @1313e right, it's a 2D array of 3D coordinates. I know the shape, but my current method starts it with d nan's and then removing them at the end of the code. If I start with an array of shape (500,3) then I wasn't sure how to add to that array 100 at a time. That would be great though, how would you write that?

Comment: @900edges But it isn't a 2D array of 3D coordinates. It is a 2D array of scalars. Please come up with a minimal example of what should go in and what the expected output of that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hpaulj stated, you can use append instead of concatenate. At the end, you can reshape the array to the desired shape.

```
#sample from d-dimensional cube
def make_cubes(d, npoints, ncubes):
    cubes = []
    for i in range(ncubes):
        c = np.random.rand(npoints, d)     #sample from cube in d dimensions
        c += np.random.uniform(-5,5)   #random translation
        cubes.append(c)
       
    cubes = np.reshape(cubes, (npoints*ncubes,d) )
    return cubes
```

For example

```
print( make_cubes(3,4,2) )
```

gave me

```
[[-0.20605781  0.17759941 -0.54688093]
 [ 0.15476342 -0.47873276 -0.66528647]
 [ 0.05216092 -0.7118765  -0.2794354 ]
 [-0.648958   -0.49131152 -0.24827643]
 [ 3.80803203  3.41893782  3.66186498]
 [ 4.37535951  3.79385615  3.52051711]
 [ 3.98299149  4.17239746  4.09716118]
 [ 3.89030706  4.26959177  4.38166707]]
```